# Backbone with dynamic views

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I am trying to achive something like this in backbone js

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        // MVC like route
        ':controller': 'defaultRoute',
        // MVC like route
        ':controller/:action': 'defaultRoute',
        // MVC like route
        ':controller/:action/:id': 'defaultRoute',
        // MVC like route
        ':controller/:action/*id': 'defaultRoute'
    },
    defaultRoute: function (controller, action, id) {
        // render view here or 
        // call another specific route regarding to controller parameter
    }
});

var appRouter = new AppRouter;
Backbone.history.start();
```

So when url is: **something.com/#home/index** defaultRoute function will get parameters **controller="home"** and **action="index"**.
I am wondering now how to find view  (Backbone.View) in folder "controller/home/index" and instantiate dynamically (and render). Also wondering if better approach would be to have Backbone.Router for each "controller" (I am using name "controller" but it is actually "router").

Any ideas?

**UPDATE with possible solution!**

I ended up with this

```
    // Filename: router.js
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function ($, _, Backbone) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            // MVC like route
            ':controller': 'defaultRoute',
            // MVC like route
            ':controller/:action': 'defaultRoute',
            // MVC like route
            ':controller/:action/:id': 'defaultRoute',
            // MVC like route
            ':controller/:action/*id': 'defaultRoute'
        },
        defaultRoute: function (controllerName, actionName, id) {
            controllerName = controllerName || Config.Defaults.Controller;
            actionName = actionName || Config.Defaults.Action;
            require(["controllers/" + controllerName], function (ctl) {
                var code = "ctl." + actionName + "();";
                eval(code);
            });
        }
    });

     var appRouter = new AppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start();
});
```

And sample controller is this

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function ($, _, Backbone) {
    return {
        index: function () {
            console.log("Action: Index");
        },
        about: function () {
            console.log("Action: About");
        }
    };
});
```

It works with this sample. Now trying to solve params binding etc. Need more testing.

Comment: nice work, it's 2015, i will steal your idea :)

Answer (score 1):

At this time I am still investigating but here is the code I am using at the moment:

```
    // Filename: router.js
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone'
], function ($, _, Backbone) {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            // MVC like route
            ':controller': 'defaultRoute',
            // MVC like route
            ':controller/:action': 'defaultRoute',
            // MVC like route
            ':controller/:action/:id': 'defaultRoute',
            // MVC like route
            ':controller/:action/*id': 'defaultRoute'
        },
        defaultRoute: function (controllerName, actionName, id) {
            controllerName = controllerName || Config.Defaults.Controller;
            actionName = actionName || Config.Defaults.Action;
            require(["controllers/" + controllerName], function (ctl) {
                var code = "ctl." + actionName + "();";
                eval(code);
            });
        }
    });

     var appRouter = new AppRouter;
        Backbone.history.start();
});
```

So "controller" looks like

```
    // Filename: controllers/home.js
define([
      'jquery',
      'underscore',
      'backbone',
    ], function ($, _, Backbone) {
        return {
            index: function () {
                require(['views/home/index'], function (view) {
                    view.render();
                });
            },
            about: function () {
                require(['views/home/about'], function (view) {
                    view.render();
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Next is to create typical backbone [views](http://backbonejs.org/#View).

I will post more when I test passing parameters and do some more complicated tests.

Comment: one question, though: how do you require an entire directory (controllers) with requirejs? surely you don't want to define the paths to each file individually in the config file? or is there no way around this? Basically, I am looking for a way to use requirejs with an entire folder, recursively.

Answer (score 0):

JS *client side dynamic dependency loading*, I think this is still in our dreams.

You can play with very tricky technics like [Dynamic Script Loading](http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html) but even if it looks easy at the beginning it is gonna become in a nightmare (sooner or later).

If you need a technic like this be sure it worths it, you should try to think it again.

About if to use one Router for the whole application or separate it in several Routers by controllers/modules or whatever I have already [said my opinion about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797168/how-to-handle-page-reloads).

Comment: Isn't requirejs library solving dynamic loading issue?

Comment: @AndrejKaurin I've never used _RequireJS_ but I think it only offers a system to load scripts on the _page load_ and not _on demand_.

Comment: RequireJS offers system to load sripts on demand. Just tested really deep on demand case.

Comment: @AndrejKaurin good to know, you should add an answer to your own question so everyone else can learn from it.